# odds/probability of single prize raffle

Tags: probability

this might seem basic but for all my searching i haven’t seen it said for single prize.

if the scenario is:

1 prize
100 tickets

player 1: 1 ticket

player 2: 1 ticket

player 3: 5 tickets

player 4: 20 tickets

player 5: 73 tickets

player 1 has 1/100 odds of winning and that’s unaffected by player 5 buying 73 tickets.

but wouldn’t players buying substantially more tickets change the possible outcome for player 1? regardless of the odds remaining the same?

appreciate any helps thanks!

Comment: Assuming that each ticket is assigned a random number, from $\{1,2,\cdots,100\}$, with the assignments done without replacement, you can assume that player-1 has the only ticket with the number $(1)$ on it.  Then, the event that the winning number is $(1)$ is independent of what other tickets are sold.  Here, I am assuming that if player-1 is the only one who bought a ticket, and the number drawn was not $(1)$, that no prize would be awarded.  ...see next comment

Comment: The assumption made at the end of my answer is actually **unrealistic**.  Typically, if the first number drawn has no **winner**, then a 2nd number is drawn.  Further, typically, this process continues until someone has a winner.  So, if person-1 is the only person who bought a ticket, then under this revised (perhaps more realistic) assumption, person-1 is certain to win.

Comment: Notice that player 1 has a $1\%$ chance of winning, player 2 also has a $1\%$ chance of winning, player 3 has a $5\%$ chance of winning, player 4 has a $20\%$ chance of winning, and that player 5 has a $73\%$ chance of winning.  These probabilities add to $100\%$ as they must.  Players with a greater percentage of the tickets have a greater chance of winning.

Answer (score 1):

If all tickets are sold, then Player 1 will have a $1\%%$ chance to win the prize. The distribution of the other tickets doesn't matter.

You may have seen a phrase in some sweepstakes stating: "The odds of winning depends on the number of entries received." Therefore, if only $20$ tickets are sold, then Player 1's odds of winning are $1/20$. Or if a thousand tickets are sold, Player 1's odds are $1/1000$, and so forth.

Comment: that makes complete sense to me. i just still can’t get over the feeling there is some difference in odds or maybe probability if i buy 1 ticket and someone buys all the others. haha i don’t know technically the answer it just feels impossible that somehow it’s the same. but maybe i just need to get over it and accept

Comment: @rjdrjd Yeah, it's a bit counterintuitive but it's the truth!